# import directory containing python src files as module

Tags: python

I've a question on importing a python directory foo as a module. The structure is:

> -- `foo`
>
> > --`__init__.py`
> >     --- `file1.py`
> >     --- `file2.py`

`__init__.py` contains the following line:
`__all__ = ["file1", "file2"]`

What I would want to do is to import foo and then access `file1` as `foo.file1` 
However, I can only access `file1` after doing:
`from foo import *`
There's a way by which I can access file1 through `foo.file1`, it is:
`from foo import *`
`import foo`
As you can see this is quite inefficient. Can someone point me to what is the right way to do what I am aiming to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package) says that `__all__` does. If you want to be able to do `foo.file1`, instead of using `__all__`, do this in `__init__.py`:

```
import file1
```